# fixed statement for a single array element

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, heap-memory, fixed

Is the following code correct inside a method?

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
unsafe
{
    fixed (int* p = &a[0])
    {
        p[1] = 3;
    }
}
```

It has no errors but since `a[0]` is fixed and `a[1]` is not fixed explicitly, there may be some GC memory move for `a[1]`.

How about this one?:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
unsafe
{
    fixed (int* p = &a[1])
    {
        p[0] = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the following assigns the address of the first element in array arr to pointer p.

```
fixed (double* p = arr)
```

is the same as

```
fixed (double* p = &arr[0])
```

in your case you assign the second element to a pointer

```
fixed (double* p = &arr[1])
```

In any case the array is pinned and protected from moving.

Answer (score 1):

The variable you pin is `a`. It's managed as a single allocation. Individual array elements will never be relocated, only the array as a whole.

Depending on your needs, you might consider using [stackalloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) instead to allocate memory on the stack rather than on the heap. Variables on the stack are not subject to GC and therefore do not need to be pinned.